# Is there an English counterpart for the unit of time `5 minutes` (一个字)?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a unit of time that is used by some Chinese speakers as `一个字` (let's call it `Z` for now). Each Z is equivalent to 5 minutes and there are 12 `Z`s in an hour. This comes primarily from my understanding of Cantonese; I don't believe this unit of time exists anywhere else outside of Cantonese.

Comment: Folks who bill hourly (like lawyers) will sometimes talk about "billing increments" which are typically tenths of an hour, i.e. ***6*** minutes. This is the closest unit of time I know of in English to "Z".

Answer (score 2):

The closest "unit" is just what you said: **five minutes**. We have to start dealing with things like *三個字* or three five minutes, i.e.: fifteen minutes. Have a look:

**ABC Canto**

> NOUN
>
> M: 個 go3
>
> 1 five minutes
>
> 仲有三個字
>
> zung6 jau5 saam1 go3 zi6
>
> We still have fifteen minutes
>
> 八點五個字
>
> baat3 dim2 ng5 go3 zi6
>
> Twenty-five minutes past eight
>
> 要行兩個字度
>
> jiu3 haang4 loeng5 go3 zi6 dou2
>
> It takes about ten minutes to walk there

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AD%97) has:

> (Cantonese, Min, Malaysia, Singapore) five minutes (derived from the locations of 1 to 12 on a clock face) (Classifier: 個／个 m c) quotations ▼
>
> 三個字 / 三个字 [Cantonese]  ―  saam1 go3 zi6 [Jyutping]  ―  fifteen minutes >[i.e. when the minute hand points to 3]
>      七點兩字 / 七点两字 [Min Nan]  ―  chhit tiám nn̄g jī [Pe̍h-ōe-jī]  ―  ten past seven

There might not be an equivalent *unit* of time in English but there are in  **Min**, **Malaysia** and **Singapore**.

Comment: Minutes is a unit of measure --- to measure 60 seconds. There's a specific word for it in English: `minutes`. There's none that I know of to measure 300 (5 x 60) seconds.

Comment: Sure, but this is the best “equivalent” you’re going to get, as far as I know.

Comment: Cantonese also use 骨 (loan word for  "quarter" ) ; 一个骨 = 15 minutes;  literary  '刻'

Comment: Informally, with sufficient context, the number may be sufficient, as in the expression *[take five](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+five)*.